# Good multi-domain + cpanel hosting server

Tags: web-development, web-server, cpanel

I am looking for a good server to host multiple domains. Cpanel is a requirement too. I usually use OVH VPS to host my sites/apps but now I need a ready-to-go server for hosting multiple sites.
Do you know which is the best choice?

Requirements:

- CPanel
- Multi-domain
- Min 20GB space
- Min 400GB/Mo transfer

Comment: There is no 'best'. Please [edit] your question and put in a specific list of (more) requirements.